# Corrupted broadcast message when system is going to halt in Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have two debian squeezy systems. On first when I've do shutdown or reboot I see correct message, for example:

```
Broadcast message from root@example.com (pts/0) (Fri Jul 19 23:43:32 2013):
The system is going down for system halt NOW!
```

But on the second system I have corrupted output:

```
The system is going down for system halt NOW!om (pts/2) (Fri Jul 19 23:45:13
```

I cant find out why message is cropped. This problem is reproduced in different terminals.

Thanks.

Comment: I would start with comparing the outputs of running `stty --all` on the terminals on both these systems.

Comment: I compared outputs, they're identical. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/Pxpvyrp9